# Recover from aborted tt-rss install

Tags: apt, uninstall, tt-rss

I tried installing tt-rss and mid way through decided I didn't want to install a DB and Web server so I aborted the install. Now I can't install any updates. Package manager is telling me to fix things with `apt-get -f install` to install anything.

When I run that I get:

```
root@cabin-htpc:/var/cache/debconf# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apache2 apache2-data apache2-utils dbconfig-common guile-2.0-libs javascript-common libandroid-properties1 libapache2-mod-php5 libcec-platform1v5
  libedataserverui-1.2-1 libfstrcmp0 libgc1c2 libjs-dojo-core libjs-dojo-dijit libjs-dojo-dojox libjs-prototype libjs-scriptaculous libmcrypt4
  libmysqlclient18 liboxideqt-qmlplugin liboxideqtcore0 liboxideqtquick0 libpgm-5.1-0 libphp-phpmailer libpoppler57 libqt5positioning5 libzmq3 mysql-common
  php-cli php-common php-gettext php-pear php-xml php5 php5-cli php5-common php5-gd php5-json php5-mcrypt php5-mysql php5-readline php7.0-cli php7.0-common
  php7.0-json php7.0-opcache php7.0-readline php7.0-xml phpqrcode qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel qml-module-qt-labs-settings
  qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin qtdeclarative5-qtfeedback-plugin qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-web-plugin signon-keyring-extension unity-webapps-qml
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  fonts-ancient-scripts indicator-sound pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils rtkit ttf-ancient-fonts unity-control-center
Suggested packages:
  unity-greeter-session-broadcast pavumeter pavucontrol paman paprefs
```

***and then the relevant part:***

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  tt-rss
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-ancient-scripts indicator-sound pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils rtkit ttf-ancient-fonts unity-control-center
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/15.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 29.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 222112 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing tt-rss (15.7+git20151123+dfsg-1) ...
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 600: /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: /etc/init.d/10: not found
invoke-rc.d: initscript 10, action "reload" failed.
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 600: /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: /etc/init.d/tt-rss/reconfigure-webserver: not found
invoke-rc.d: initscript tt-rss/reconfigure-webserver, action "reload" failed.
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 600: /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: /etc/init.d/doesn't: not found
invoke-rc.d: initscript doesn't, action "reload" failed.
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 600: /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: /etc/init.d/exist: not found
invoke-rc.d: initscript exist, action "reload" failed.
update-rc.d: error: cannot find a LSB script for tt-rss
dpkg: error processing package tt-rss (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tt-rss
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@cabin-htpc:/var/cache/debconf#
```

I've tried

```
apt-get remove tt-rss
apt-get purge tt-rss
dpkg -r tt-rss
dpkg -P tt-rss
```

I'm guessing that 'reload" is the uninstaller trying to reload the web server and DB server that never got installed. I just have no idea what to do about it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the best way, but I eventually went into:
`/var/lib/dpkg/info`

and found the tt-rss pre and post install/remove files

`tt-rss.postrm
tt-rss.prerm`

which I renamed to:

`tt-rss.postrm.backup
tt-rss.prerm.backup`

With those disabled:
`dpkg --purge --force-all tt-rss`
worked to purge and remove tt-rss.